# How to know if react-router can go back to display back button in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, html5-history

There seems to be no API way to detect if you can go back from the current page in an app. One can check the history length, but that includes the forward and backward stack.

I want to display the back button only when the user actually can go back.

Answer (score 24):

You can check `location.key` if you have a location key that means you routed in-app. But if you don't that means you come from outside of the app or you just open the app in a new tab etc.

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    if (location.key) {
      history.goBack();
    }
  }}
  disabled={!location.key}
/>;
```

For V6 and newer:

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    if (location.key !== 'default') {
      history.goBack();
    }
  }}
  disabled={location.key === 'default'}
/>;
```

Comment: +1, This worked for me, although I wish I could put my hands on some documentation that stated plainly that a newly opened tab would always have a key of NULL.

Comment: WARNING: With the latest version React Router V6 you have to check for "default" instead of an empty string. Now your initial location is "default" instread of "". Read API reference: https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location

Comment: note `location.key` will be "default" if the user navigates via the URL bar. edge case but true

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by checking `history.action` if its value is `POP`, then there is no route to go back. That's the only way I found.

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    if (history.action !== 'POP') history.goBack();
  }}
  disabled={history.action === 'POP'}
/>
```

Comment: The action property specifies the last action of the router, it doesn't have anything to do with the remaining items in the history stack.

Comment: If the user refreshes the page it will go back to "POP". So it won't work in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a workaround

There is [onpopstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate):

Calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. **The popstate event is only triggered by performing a browser action**, such as clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript), when navigating between two history entries for the same document.

And I checked it: react router saves at state a key property: 
On history walking it may contains a data like: 
**event.state: {key: "jr2go2", state: undefined}**

And when we go back to last page on wich we entered the site or app, this state property will be null:
**event.state: null**
,

So we can handle it with redux + rxjs (for example) like this:

```
// epic
export const handleHistoryWalkEpic = () =>
  fromEvent<PopStateEvent>(window, 'popstate')
  .pipe(
    map(event => setCanGoBack(!!event.state)),
  )

// reducer
case NavigationBarActionsTypes.SET_CAN_GO_BACK:
  return {
    ...state,
    canGoBack: action.payload.canGoBack,
  }
```

And you should set canGoBack to true on any push history action, it's possible with your any router handler component:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps: any) {
    let { location } = this.props;

    if (nextProps.history.action === 'PUSH') {
      this.props.setCanGoBack()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking if `location.history` is > 2.

Example to show or not the back button in your app:

```
onBack={ history.length > 2 ? () => { history.goBack() } : null }
```

Comment: why `2` specifically?

Comment: @EdwardSammutAlessi if history length has 1 only that means that you don't navigate in the stack yet so you cant go back. Only if the stack have minimum 2 elements that means that you can go back in the stack navigation. Does make sense to you?

Comment: It is not a solution. Assume you've opened page #1 (`history.length` is `1`), then you go to next page #2 (`history.length` is `2`), then again - to #3 (`history.length` is `3`). Now you go back from #3 to #1, `history.length` is still `3` but at page #1 you have nowhere to go back.

Comment: I found if I open a new Chrome tab and goto a page history.length is always 2

Comment: but if you go back, history.length doesn't decrease

Answer (score 0):

```
react-router 7.4.1 
react router-dom 6.21.1
```

Unfortunately, none of the solutions provided here were helpful for me. However, the following proved to be useful:

```
const canGoBack = window.history.state.idx !== 0
const canGoForward = window.history.state.idx < window.history.length - 1

<button disabled={!canGoBack}>go back</button>
<button disabled={!canGoForward}>go forward</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

it gives 'POP' and 'PUSH' value `using this.props.location.action`

Comment: if we move back, it gives 'POP' action, that way you can detect it