# How do I find out if it's possible to goBack() or goForward() using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

If user has navigated to another route, he can be navigated back to the previous page.
If user has navigated back, he can be navigated forward to the previous page.

In `react-native`, `react-nativation` provides useNavigation hook so I can simply perform:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigation} from 'react-navigation'

function Test()
{
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    return (
       
        <div>
            { navigation.canGoBack() && <button onClick=(() => navigation.goBack())>Go Back</button>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

in `ReactJS`, `react-router` provides `useHistory` hook so I can perform `history.goBack()` but not `history.canGoBack()`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

function Test()
{
    const history = useHistory()
    return (
       
        <div>
            { history.canGoBack() && <button onClick=(() => history.goBack())>Go Back</button>

            {/* history.canGoBack() is not a function  */}

        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Does react-router provide a method to let us know if we can go back or forward?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it doesn't solve the question. The first answer on this question looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385570/how-to-know-if-react-router-can-go-back-to-display-back-button-in-react-app

Answer (score 0):

```
import {History} from 'react-router';
var canGoBack = (History.length > 1);
```

Can you please try this one? I think this may solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, that works fine for navigating back. What about forward? There must be a better approach for both.