# How can I determine whether the app can navigate forward in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is quite similar to this question here: [How to know if react-router can go back to display back button in react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385570/how-to-know-if-react-router-can-go-back-to-display-back-button-in-react-app) where the ask is regarding determining whether the user can go back in the app.

That answered half the question. The other half: How do I determine whether the user can move forward? I knew this could be possible with access to the history which was possible in v5, but since v6, useHistory doesn't exist anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this through the v6 version of `react-router-dom` either.

There is an experimental Navigation API property called `canGoForward` (and `canGoback`) that I found to work with `react-router-dom`:

```js
// Defaults to true for browsers that don't support the property
const canGoForward = !window.navigation || window.navigation.canGoForward || window.navigation.canGoForward !== false ? true : false
```

See the `navigation.canGoForward` documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/canGoForward

It doesn't work on all browsers though, I would be keen to use a more robust solution that utilises the react router.